# Grizzy/Jersey: POJO-mapping does not work with Maven one-jar

Tags: java, maven, jersey, grizzly

I created a simple [project on github](https://github.com/boldt/Simple-Jersey-Example) (see the sources there).

If I import the project as a Maven-project in Eclipse and run it, I can curl the XML/JSON resources.

If I create a one-jar with `mvn package` and run the jar it, I cannot curl the XML/JSON resources. I am getting the following errors:

`Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class de.dennis_boldt.resources.User, and Java type class de.dennis_boldt.resources.User, and MIME media type application/xml was not found`

`Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class de.dennis_boldt.resources.User, and Java type class de.dennis_boldt.resources.User, and MIME media type application/json was not found`

Do I miss something? Maybe a Maven dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the `maven-shade-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Main-Class>package.Main</Main-Class>
                            <Build-Number>1</Build-Number>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                </transformers>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```